# How to estimate a single AR model for multiple time series?

Tags: time-series, estimation, stochastic-processes, autoregressive, acf-pacf

I have ACF of a time series data, I want to interpolate the ACF using AR model for which I need to calculate the coefficient of the AR model The problem is I have (6000x6000) matrix of ACF and I cant use individual sequence calculate the coefficients. Is there any method or algorithm available through which I can use a single model which can combine the information of all ACF to generate the coefficients of AR model? I have read a paper about the Burg algorithm for the segments of the data that effectively combines the data, but can I use that algorithm here for ACF?

Comment: What do you mean "I cant use individual sequence calculate the coefficients"? If you have ACF up to 6000 lags, you can compute AR(p) coefficients for any chosen p < 5999 by solving the Yule-Walker equations. (In other words, estimate the AR(p) model via method of moments.)

Comment: I have 6000x6000 matrix so I have 6000 sequences and i want to extend all of them further by AR model, so I have to consider each sequence individually to calculate the AR coefficients, so my question was, :Is there any method or algorithm which can combine the information of all the sequences simultaneously  and generate common values of AR coefficients of pth order.

Comment: So each row of your matrix is the sample ACF up to 6000 lags (computed using a sample of some size you didn't specify), and you have 6000 such rows/samples. Your assumption is that all 6000 samples are generated by the same AR(p) model.

Comment: If that's the case, that is a very rare situation in time series. Typically one gets 1 sample path. You have 6000 sample paths. The first naive thing to try is take the sample mean of sample ACF at each lag across the 6000 sample paths, then estimate your chosen AR model in the usual way.

Comment: Thanks Micheal for your reply, actually I have time series data of 12000 samples, I applied ACF to the whole data, and then separated 6000 samples from it, I want to calculate the remaining part through AR model through these 6000 samples. I have tried this ' mean" method but didnt get the desired answers and model was unstable. Although, when I apply Burg algorithm developed for multiple segments (considering each row a separate segment of the data), the model were stable, but does it make any sense, considering each sample path, a segment of the data?